# Serial DC-link Capacitor to increase the effective voltage rating

Tags: inverter, electrolytic-capacitor

I am developing a 2-phase motor driver system, which requires my inverter's DC-link to be near 480V. 480V is used to generate 2 line-line voltage of 220Vac(using 3-phase inverter).

The Aluminium capacitor at 650V are too expensive and bulky. I am thinking of serially connecting the capacitor with added voltage margin to account for unbalanced voltage sharing. Is using 2 400Vdc Al cap in series a good idea ?

EDIT: So as suggested, I can balance the voltage across the capacitor using parallel resistor. How should I calculate the value of the resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwInDs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You need to add a picture of that.

Comment: You need bleeder resistors to cope with worst case scenario missmatch in leakage current. Al E-cap craps out at 450 V, so this is where you usually end up unless you go plastic.

Comment: ESR doesn't unbalance series caps, but difference in leakage current does. The bleeders have to be small enough to not just discharge the capacitors safely when powered off, but also to swamp any difference in the leakage current so the mid point doesn't drift too far away from the mid voltage.

Comment: It's a 2KW motor, I am expecting Irms flowing through the caps to be within 3Amps. So now how to select the value of the resistor, I found a PDF stating to use R=10/C, is this good? Or I should find the expected leakage current, then calculate the resistor value for the extreme case.